# what is difference between graph api and c# SDK for facebook

Tags: facebook

Can any one explain that what is difference between grap API and Visual studio SDK for facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Graph API is a new and a lot easier way to access facebook API, it can be used from any language including C#.

> The new Graph API attempts to
>   drastically simplify the way
>   developers read and write data to
>   Facebook. It presents a simple,
>   consistent view of the Facebook social
>   graph, uniformly representing objects
>   in the graph (e.g., people, photos,
>   events, and fan pages) and the
>   connections between them (e.g., friend
>   relationships, shared content, and
>   photo tags).

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Also have a look at:

- [View exactly what the Facebook Graph API is exposing, for you or anyone else](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/04/28/view-exactly-what-the-facebook-graph-api-is-exposing-for-you-or/)

On the other hand, C# SDK is a way to use facebook API through C# only. Facebook has created SDK for more languages too other than C#.